# Run time error - after settting enabled 32 bit application to false IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, 32bit-64bit

I had a old application running in asp which was migrated to **.net** recently and was deployed on **Windows 2008 server** but it was still being run in 32 bits due to some dll (old MSXML dll was being used) dependency.
The dependency was removed and it was rebuild on 2012 VS. When I deploy and change the app pool setting to disable 32 bit application flag (under advanced settings), it gives me following error.
However if i change the flag to true the application starts working again.
Can anyone suggest some solution please?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\*******\******\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/70aa83e0/80464c61/System.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/70aa83e0/80464c61/System.Web/System.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Websites/XML_NET/bin/System.Web.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Sounds like your 64 bit process - IIS' worker process w3wp.exe, which hosts your .net code - attempted to load some assembly that is compiled for 32 bits (with x86 as the target).

Ensure that the application and all of its dependencies are compiled with the target set to AnyCPU or x64.

Comment: thanks MA HAnin, i was checking the list of dependencies added and apart from one custom code (that i need to check to ensure its build with target set as any cpu or *64), i can see i have microsoft.visualbasic dll..can this dll be built for 32 bits? Is there any way i can see what each dependencies are build for i.e. 32 , 64 etc?

Comment: Anybody - anyways of finding out the target CPU for all the dll referenced in your solution in vs 2012?